# Regular expression replacement

Tags: c#, regex

I ve got the following reg exp

```
(-[^\w+])|([\w+]-[\w+])
```

I want to use it to replace dashes with a whitespace

```
test -test             should not be replaced
test - test            should be replaced
test-test              should be replaced
```

So only if **test -test** the dash should NOT be replaced.

Currently *([\w+]-[\w+])* is replacing the t's around the dash.

```
        var specialCharsExcept = new Regex(@"([\w+]-[\w+])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
            return "";

        return specialCharsExcept.Replace(term, " ");
```

Any help? Thanks in advance

PS: I am using C#.

**Update**

I'm trying to use your reg exp for the following case now.

```
some - test "some test"   - everything within the quotes the expression should not be applied
```

Is this possible?

Comment: should be replaced with what?

Comment: Are you sure it is `[\w+]` instead of `\w+`? The former matches all alphanumerics (and `_`) as well as the plus sign.

Comment: A dash should be replaced with a whitespace

Comment: Chris - I suggest you start a new question, this is different enough from your original question. But don't be too optimistic, matching quotes it not an ideal task for a regex, unless you have clear limitations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this crazy one:

```
-(?!\w(?<=\s-\w))
```

This regex:

- Searches for a dash that isn't followed by a (letter with a space two characters before it).
- Takes care of `test- test` and `-test`, which you don't have in your test cases.
- Selects only the dash, so you can replace it (this really what made the definition so complicated).

By the way - you don't need `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` because your regex has no literal parts, you aren't tryting to captrue `/test/` from `"Test TEST".` This will do:

```
Regex specialCharsExcept = new Regex(@"-(?!\w(?<=\s-\w))");
return specialCharsExcept.Replace(term, " ");
```

Comment: Regexp can be trully difficult :-O

Comment: Can you tell me how to extend this expression to disable this rule as soon as "test -test" is enclosed with quotes? like: some -test "some -test", the content within the quotes should not be replaced

Answer (score 1):

Ok, changed according to comment.

```
>>> r = ' +(-) +|(?<=\w)-(?=\w)'
>>> re.sub(r, ' ', 'test - test')
'test test'
>>> re.sub(r, ' ', 'test-test')
'test test'
>>> re.sub(r, ' ', 'test -test')
'test -test'
```

**EDIT** Corrected according to comment. The trick is to add the 'lookahead  assertion' with `?=` and the lookbehind with `?<=`, which not be part of the match, but will be checked.

Comment: not exactly, I just want to replace the dash, not the whole input
The second example should return substitution as well. On line if test -test, the dash may stay.

Comment: I've edited it. It also strips blank spaces on the second case.

Comment: According to the test cases, the dash on `test-test` should also be replaced. `(?=\w)-` is a lookahead, so it's looking for a dash that is a letter - should be look behind. also, consider using `r` in your sample code, it will become more readable.

Comment: @Kobi. You're absolutely right, I don't know how I thought I've made it :-( I was convinced I'd used the `r`. I've added the lookbehind mark.

Comment: Really an atrocity :-P On my code, usually a regular expression is preceded with three or four lines explaining it (at least in Python you can comment them inside)e